# Dynatree ASP.NET MVC: post tree to server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, serialization, dynatree

I want to post data from dynatree to my asp.net mvc server via ajax. I use the model classes ([Dynatree with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598621/dynatree-with-asp-net-mvc)) from Steve which work well for getting data from the server to the client. But i have still problems with posting the tree data to the server.

Client:

```
 var td = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree").toDict();
 var json = JSON.stringify(td);

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/parttree",
        data: json,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

Server:

```
[POST("/parttree")]
public ActionResult TreeData2( List<TreeItem>  ot)
{
    // ot is always null here
}
```

Content of `json` in VS debugger: 
{"title":null,"key":"_1","isFolder":false,"isLazy":true,"tooltip":null,"href":null,"icon":null,"addClass":null,"noLink":false,"activate":false,"focus":false,"expand":true,"select":false,"hideCheckbox":false,"unselectable":false,"children":[{"title":"root","key":"_2","isFolder":false,"isLazy":false,"tooltip":null,"href":null,"icon":null,"addClass":null,"noLink":false,"activate":false,"focus":false,"expand":false,"select":false,"hideCheckbox":false,"unselectable":false,"children":....

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it would be the following :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/parttree",
        data: {tree: json},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

And your MVC Action would be :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PartTree(FormCollection form)
    {
        List<TreeItem> ot =  new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<TreeItem>>(form["tree"]);

    }
```

Although you are probably looking to a JsonResult not an ActionResult if you are returning JSON.

Comment: The controller function is not called with your solution

Comment: [POST("/parttree")]
public ActionResult TreeData2(FormCollection form)

Comment: I have never seen that syntax before. But if you use the formcollection and cast it to List<TreeItem> it should be fine. If you note that I have named the object tree in the ajax call - data: {tree: json}

Comment: [POST("/parttree")] is attributerouting and the function is called with  my solution but not with yours?

Comment: Either that or :  List<TreeItem> ot =  new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<TreeItem>>(Request.Form["tree"]);

Comment: the controller method is not called.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30769/discussion-between-steve-and-zoidbergi)